# SXS: BasepCreateActCtx() BasepSxsCreateStreams() failed Error occured in runtime

Tags: windows, driver, windbg, minifilter

I have encountered errors like this while testing product build on Windows 10 x64 1903 release where my driver were installed (it was virtual machine). I can not guess what happens and Google does not help me find any information which may be useful (any information!!!).

SXS: BasepCreateActCtx() BasepSxsCreateStreams() failed

SXS: BasepCreateActCtx() BasepSxsCreateStreams() failed

WER/CrashExp:380: ERROR Failed to create the process "C:\Windows\system32\WerFault.exe", cmdline 
"C:\Windows\system32\WerFault.exe -u -p 7128 -s 964", creationflags 525312, HRESULT 800705AA

SXS: Unable to open registry key

\Registry\Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\AssemblyStorageRoots Status = 0xc000009a

SXS: RtlGetAssemblyStorageRoot() unable to resolve storage map entry.  Status = 0xc0000120
SXS: BasepCreateActCtx() BasepSxsCreateStreams() failed

SXS: BasepCreateActCtx() BasepSxsCreateStreams() failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was very simple I just forgot to uncheck randomized low resources simulation in driver verifier.